# How to get value from XAML after clicking a submit button in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to retrieve a value from the Entry input after clicking an event. How can I retrieve it. Following is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Spacing="10" x:Name="layout">

        <Label Text="Name" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Large"/>

        <Entry x:Name="name" Placeholder="Enter your name"/>


        <Label Text="Password" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Large"/>

        <Entry x:Name="password" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="****"/>

        <Label Text="Date of Birth" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Large"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="dob"/>

        <Label Text="Gender" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Large"/>

        <Picker x:Name="GenderPicker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Male</x:String>
                <x:String>Female</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>

        <Button x:Name="submit" Text="Save" BorderWidth="20" Clicked="submit_Clicked"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And i want to retrieve the data in a submit_Clicked() method.

```
      private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
how?
        }
```

Comment: I think what the op meant was like in winforms we had the tag property xamrain doesnt have that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get value from `Entry.Text` property. For example:

```
private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var nameValue = name.Text;
}
```

Comment: This answer covers your question completely, but I feel I should mention that code behind should generally be used for dealing with UI stuff, while the ViewModel should be the one that does any business stuff, processes values, computations, data layer interactions, etc. You should probably look into  binding a Command to that button and binding the Entry's Text property to a string property in your ViewModel

Comment: Yes, I know that. In our projects we use MVVM-pattern. but you're definitely right about view model

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Entry entry = e as Entry;
     var text=entry.Text;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entry_name = new Entry {Placeholder= "name" };//for getting value of Entry name
    var entry_password = new Entry {Placeholder ="password" };
    var text=entry_name.Text;
    var password= entry_password.Text;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Below how you can do it, you might need to cast it first.

```
private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Entry entry = sender as Entry;
   var text=entry.Text;
}
```

Comment: As you can see - sender it's `Button`

Comment: This is completely wrong. The handler in question is the Button click handler. It's sender property will be the button that was clicked. This type of cast and value retrieval would work on an Entry's TextChanged event, for example.

Comment: Interesting how this answer has -5 votes, whereas Prashant Bamania has +2, even though their answers are pretty much identical.